# My screen randomly goes black

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, screen, freeze

I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 20.04.  Now I have an issue where my screen will suddenly go black and the computer freezes.  This happens randomly after a few hours of use.  I don't think it is an overheating issue, since it happens even if I am not doing anything.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Kernel: 5.4.0-122-generic
- Machine: Dell Inspiron 7559
- VGA: HD Graphics 530
- GPU : GeForce GTX 960M
- Nvidia driver: 515.48.07  (this is the recommended driver)
- CUDA Version: 11.7
- RAM: 16GiB DDR3

Comment: What happens if you connect an external monitor to your laptop? Does the external monitor screen also go black and freeze?

Comment: @karel Hi, yes the external monitor also goes black.

Comment: Maybe Dell Inspiron 7559 has a hardware issue, maybe not. What happens when you run a live Ubuntu session from a live Ubuntu USB?